# How to write PHP username welcome message inside HTML?

Tags: php, html

This is my php code to display welcome user into the page if the username and password is correct.

```
$_SESSION['userName'] = $usernm;
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['userName']."!";
```

I wanted to display the variable name inside this tag, cuz my css coding hav some styles for li and href tags. Please help me...

```
<li><a href="#">Welcome User!</a></li>
```

Comment: What do you get as output right now?

Comment: you may want to add code and output... not really sure I understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

Heres how to echo `$_SESSIONS` or any php variables inside tag.

You can also add additional if else condition in for `$_SESSION` to determine whether your session is set or not

```
<li><a href="#">Welcome <?php  if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])){echo $_SESSION['userName'];}else{ echo 'Session not set';}?>.!</a></li>
```

Comment: You forgot the actual echo/print function

Comment: kaii! your answer almost worked. But still the message is nt clear! even after i refresh and relogin, the same message displays.. "Welcome Session not set.!"

Comment: @FranklinVaz that means passing `$usernm` value to `$_SESSION['userName']` failed..

Comment: did you first use `session_start();` before passing up the value of `$usernm` to session

Comment: heres another on to check before `$_SESSION['userName'] = $usernm;` .write an if else condition if(isset($usernm)){ echo $usernm;}else{ echo 'Variable is not set';}

Comment: this will tell you $usernm is set.

Answer (score 2):

Just some simple string concatenation will do

```
echo "<li><a href='#'>Welcome ".$_SESSION['userName']."!</a></li>";
```

Comment: No its not working.. the variable name is not coming inside the tag when i refresh the page or relogin to th page! please help

Comment: @FranklinVaz do you call `session_start()` on each page?

Comment: @FranklinVaz are you sure that `$usernm` is set?

Comment: I am very sure! can you fix my prob? i going mad on this :( i need to solve this prob. Shall i mail you my code?

Answer (score 2):

Check this one:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['userName'] = $usernm;
?>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?>!</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or maybe this one:

```
<?php
$usernm = $_SESSION['userName'];
?>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Welcome <?php echo $usernm; ?>!</a></li>
</ul>
```